# How to include namespace in XSL transformation in XML

Tags: java, xml, xslt, namespaces, xslt-1.0

I am trying to transform an xml file to another xml file using JAVA. After transformation the new xml will have a set of sub elements and required namespaces. However I am not able to include the specific required namespaces. It is either all or none. Can someone help on this pls ?

Input XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ns2:root 
    xmlns="http://uri1.com" 
    xmlns:ns2="http://uri2.com">
    <element1>
        <elementA1>
            <elementB1>AA</elementB1>            
        </elementA1>
        <elementA2>12345</elementA2>
        <elementA3>A 000</elementA3>
     </element1>
</ns2:root>
```

Expected Output XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <element1 xmlns="http://uri1.com" >
        <elementA1>
            <elementB1>AA</elementB1>            
        </elementA1>
        <elementA2>12345</elementA2>
        <elementA3>A 000</elementA3>
     </element1>
```

XSL file I am using

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <!-- <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="utf-8"/> -->

  <!-- For each element, create a new element with the same local-name (no namespace) -->
  <xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
      <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/> 
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Skip the root element, just process its children. -->
  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Current Output XML ( without namespaces )

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <element1>
        <elementA1>
            <elementB1>AA</elementB1>            
        </elementA1>
        <elementA2>12345</elementA2>
        <elementA3>A 000</elementA3>
     </element1>
```

Java code used to do XSL transformation

```
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.io.StringWriter;

import javax.xml.transform.Templates;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;

public final class XsltTransformer {

  private Templates templates;

  public XsltTransformer(final String xslFilePath) {
    String xslt = FileUtils.getAsString(xslFilePath);
    try {
      this.templates = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTemplates(new StreamSource(new StringReader(xslt)));
    } catch (Exception e) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Error while creating XLST transformer with XSLT text [" + xslt + "]", e);
    }
  }

  public String applyTransformation(final String inputXml) {
    try {
      StreamSource in = new StreamSource(new StringReader(inputXml));
      StreamResult out = new StreamResult(new StringWriter());     
      templates.newTransformer().transform(in, out);
      return out.getWriter().toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unable to transform input XML [" + inputXml + "]", e);
    }
  }

}
```

Can someone help me on adding specific namespace as in the expected output XML??
Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So finally I found a way to hack the result by using default namespace. All above answers are working fine and this one works with Java Transformation as well.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
     xmlns:ns1="http://uri1.com" 
    xmlns:ns2="http://uri2.com">
  <!-- For each element, create a new element with the same local-name (no namespace) -->
  <xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
      <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/> 
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Skip the root element, just process its children. -->
  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:template>

  <!--override the new root element and insert the default namespace -->
  <xsl:template match="/ns2:root/ns1:element1">
        <xsl:element name="element1"
            xmlns="http://uri1.com">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your Stylesheet tag, declare the default namespace as:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns="http://uri1.com">
```

Comment: I tried that and almost spent a day on this now ;-;. Hopefully I can fix this today :P

Comment: Btw, adding namespace isn't helping.

Comment: Feeling sad to see that working normally but not on Java XML transformation :(.. Thanks for the help :) Seems I got so many solutions now. Have to figure out how to make it work on java.

Comment: Which java processor are you using? Xalan, which is implemented in java works just fine.

Comment: defaul xml functions bundled with jdk. I have added that code in my post as formatting doesn't work in comments.

Answer (score 1):

The result you want can be achieved simply by removing the root wrapper:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/*">
    <xsl:copy-of select="*"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note that this will leave a redundant namespace declaration `xmlns:ns2="http://uri2.com"` but that should not be a problem unless your target application is non-conforming.

Comment: target application isn't complaining but I am caching those XML values and thought it would be nice if I could get rid of that additional namespace but guess no simple way ?

Comment: I don't think you need to worry about it. In order to remove it, you must rebuild every element instead of copying it, like you have started to do, or as shown in the answer by Mathias Müller.

Comment: I tried to construct the whole xml itself on hand by xml:element and value of tags. But few elements are optional and as a newbie I am not sure how to handle those optional tags.

Comment: As you did, by matching *any* element using `<xsl:template match="*">`. The only problem with your attempt is that you did not put the new elements in the desired namespace. You can do that globally - as suggested by Madeyedexter - or explicitly, as suggested by Mathias Müller.

Comment: I will check that .

Comment: Thanks for the help throughout mate. Finally managed to insert a default namespace. Although this is not a proper solution, it will do for now. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a transformation that gives exactly the result you expected.

In your stylesheet, you have to *redeclare* the namespaces that were present in your input document if you need to find specific elements. Then you can refer to elements that are in a namespace with a *prefix*, e.g. `ns1:`.

When you construct new elements with `xsl:element`, you can add an attribute `namespace`, which will result in a *default namespace* for the new elements.

**Stylesheet**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:ns2="http://uri2.com">

  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}" namespace="http://uri1.com">
      <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/> 
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/ns2:root">
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XML Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<element1 xmlns="http://uri1.com">
   <elementA1>
      <elementB1>AA</elementB1>
   </elementA1>
   <elementA2>12345</elementA2>
   <elementA3>A 000</elementA3>
</element1>
```

Try it online [here](http://xsltransform.net/pPJ8LVP).

Comment: That works perfectly fine. Guess something goes wrong when I run that xsl on java though. namespace information gets added to every element individually. I will try to see what went wrong. Thanks for the help.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><ns0:element1 xmlns:ns0="http://uri1.com">
<ns1:elementA1 xmlns:ns1="http://uri1.com">
<ns2:elementB1 xmlns:ns2="http://uri1.com">AA</ns2:elementB1>
</ns1:elementA1>
<ns3:elementA2 xmlns:ns3="http://uri1.com">12345</ns3:elementA2>
<ns4:elementA3 xmlns:ns4="http://uri1.com">A 000</ns4:elementA3>
</ns0:element1>